# C++ implementing is_convertible & references

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I have created following trait template class to determine, whether one type can be converted to another:

```
namespace Detail
{
    struct IsConvertible
    {
        template <typename _Type, typename _OtherType>
        static void convert(_OtherType);
        template <typename _Type, typename _OtherType>
        static auto test(_Type&&, _OtherType&&) -> decltype(convert<_Type, _OtherType>(std::declval<_Type>()), std::true_type());
        static auto test(...) -> decltype(std::false_type());
    };
}
template <typename _Type, typename _OtherType>
struct IsConvertible : public decltype(Detail::IsConvertible::test(std::declval<_Type>(), std::declval<_OtherType>()))
{};
```

And then tried following test cases:

```
void func1(int& i) {

}
void func2(int i) {

}
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    cout << IsConvertible<int, long>::value;
    cout << IsConvertible<int, float>::value;
    cout << IsConvertible<int, int*>::value;
    cout << IsConvertible<float, double>::value;
    cout << IsConvertible<int&, int>::value;
    cout << IsConvertible<int, int&>::value;

    int i = 2;
    int& ir = i;
    int* ip = &i;

    func1(i);
    func2(ir);

    return 0;
}
```

I am using MSVC 2015. Output of these tests was:

```
110110
```

It correctly handles numeric promotions & conversions, but it have problems with reference conversions. What is problem with this implementation?

**Edit:** I updated tests & compared my results with std::is_convertible. The results are identical.

Comment: Is this for learning purposes - i.e. `std::is_converible<>` is not good enough? you may want to handle references (`is_reference<>` and then maybe remove reference and then check the types?)

Comment: Are there any differences or limitations between expressions in unevaluated context and normal expressions according to standard?

Comment: "It matches `std::is_convertible` exactly. What's wrong?"

Comment: Well, those functions calls shows that reference is convertible to value and vice versa. But when I added lvalue reference to declval parameter as you suggested in comment, I got true result even in last case.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your question is slightly unclear. It can be argued that "X &" can be converted to "X", if the type can be copy- or move-constructed; it can also be argued that they are different types, and cannot be converted.

Given that one of your test cases results in the "convertible" result between an `int` and a `long`, I'm going to assume that your expected results are "loose". That is, if there's any way to convert from `foo` to `bar`, then the results are yes, and that your issue is with:

```
cout << IsConvertible<int, int&>::value;
```

giving the result of "false", but you expect that: well, if I have an `int` lying around, I should be able to turn it into an `int &`, sure, not a problem.

That's my assumption. So, let's see where this conversion goes off the rails:

```
convert<_Type, _OtherType>(std::declval<_Type>()),
```

You're using SFINAE here. `_Type` is `int`. `_OtherType` is `int &`.

By the way, you should not use identifiers that begin with an underscore and followed by an uppercase letter. They're reserved for use by the C++ library.

Your `convert` template is:

```
template <typename _Type, typename _OtherType>
    static void convert(_OtherType);
```

So, for this template instantiation, you're going to instantiate

```
static void convert(int &);
```

With your invocation being:

```
convert(std::declval<int>());
```

The instantiation of `std::declval<int>` will return an int, and the result of the function call to `std::declval<int>`() will be an rvalue.

This function call fails because an `int` rvalue cannot bind to an `int &` function call parameter, only to a `const int &` parameter. In other words, with:

```
int declval();

void convert(int &);
```

the following fails:

```
convert(declval());
```

And that's why your SFINAE substitution fails, and the conversion fails.

I'm going to suggest a slightly alternative approach:

```
template<typename Type> class TypeValue {

public:

    static TypeValue param;
};
```

Then, instead of using `std::declval`, use something like this:

```
convert<_Type, _OtherType>(TypeValue<_Type>::param),
```

Comment: `is_convertible` has a very precise specification. The "alternative approach" is a more complicated way to write `std::declval<T&>()` with the extra drawback that it doesn't work with, at a minimum, abstract or function types.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overload reference or pointer operators.
You can typeid(x).name(). This will give you the type name of x. 
You could create a container like this one:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    #define TYPES_CNV_COUNT 1
    typedef void**(*__CONVERT_FUNC__)(void*);

    void** cnv_str(void* _elm){
        void** a = new void*[2];
        a[0] = new string((const char*)_elm);
        a[1] = _elm;
        return (a);
    }
    class Converter{
    public:
        Converter(){
            m_mTypes.insert(pair<string, int>(typeid(string).name(), 0));
            m_mConvertFunc[0].insert(pair<string, __CONVERT_FUNC__>(typeid(const char*).name(), (__CONVERT_FUNC__)&cnv_str));
        }
        int  isCnv(const string& _nameElm1, const string& _nameElm2)const{
            map<string, int>::const_iterator itCnv = m_mTypes.find(_nameElm1);
            map<string, __CONVERT_FUNC__>::const_iterator itCnvFunc;
            int index;
            if (itCnv == m_mTypes.end())
                return (-1);
            itCnvFunc = m_mConvertFunc[index = itCnv->second].find(_nameElm2);
            if (itCnvFunc == m_mConvertFunc[index].end())
                return (-1);
            return (itCnv->second);
        }
        void** cnv(const string& _nameElm1, const string& _nameElm2,void* _elm)const{
            int index = isCnv(_nameElm1, _nameElm2);

            if (index > -1)
            {
                map<string, __CONVERT_FUNC__>::const_iterator itCnvFunc = m_mConvertFunc[index].find(_nameElm2);
                return ((*(itCnvFunc->second))(_elm));
            }
            return (NULL);
        }
    private:
        map<string, int>               m_mTypes;
        map<string, __CONVERT_FUNC__> m_mConvertFunc[TYPES_CNV_COUNT];
    };

    int main(void){
        Converter cnv;
        string hello = "hello";
        const char* world = "world";
        void** e;

        if (cnv.isCnv(string(typeid(hello).name()), string(typeid(world).name())) > -1){
            cout << "convertable!\n";
        }
        else{
            cout << "not convertable!\n";
        }

        if ((e = cnv.cnv(string(typeid(hello).name()), string(typeid(world).name()),(void*)world)) != NULL){
            cout << "type: " << typeid(*(string*)e[0]).name() << endl;
            cout << "data: " << ((string*)e[0])->c_str() << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "failed to convert" << endl;
        }

        system("pause");
        delete e[0];
        delete[] e;
        return (0);
    }
```